# Sql Database design hierarchy

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, hierarchical-data

I have been tasked to create an app to track our contracts. I am planing to use Django and PostgreSQL.

Our existing data is in Excel with 52 rows.

I have found an hierarchy pattern in the file which contains as below

1. Holding Office
2. Registered Office
3. Operating Office

For example - Holding office (company) can contain one more Registered Office (company) and in-turn registered office (company) can contain one more operating office(Company).

1st I thought I can create 3 tables and map them using PK and FK. But what if in the future they wanted to change the  hierarchy from 3 to 4 or 5, how to I design a database to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically done using a pattern called the ["adjacency list model"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).

```
create table office
(
  office_id integer primary key, 
  office_name varchar(50) not null unique,
  parent_office_id integer references office
);
```

Note that `parent_office_id` is nullable to indicate "no parent".

You can then build up the structure like this:

```
insert into office (office_id, office_name, parent_office_id)
values
(1, 'Holding Office', null),
(2, 'Registered Office One', 1),
(3, 'Registered Office Two', 1),
(4, 'Operating Office One', 2),
(5, 'Operating Office Two', 2),
(6, 'Operating Office Three', 3);
```

You can get all "child" offices using a [recursive query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html). There are a [lot of examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+recursive-query) on Stackoverflow for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few trade-offs here - there's even a (really good) [book](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Joe_Celko_s_Trees_and_Hierarchies_in_SQL.html?id=uw2lq2o4VbUC&redir_esc=y) outlining the options.

@a_horse_with_no_name gives the most [commonly used example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63029908/626692).

The benefits of this model are that you're not hard-wiring the nature of the relationships into the data model. When you find a registered office without a holding company, you don't need to unpick your "3 table" model to accommodate that. You might include an "office_type" column so your UI can show the office types without making inferences from the relationships.

Other benefits are that it's easy to change the hierarchy - a registered office can easily be transferred to another holding company, along with all its children.

The drawbacks are that you cannot easily enforce the business rules in the data model. If there is a business rule that says "all registered offices must belong to exactly one registered office", you cannot create referential integrity constraints to enforce that.